# Design pattern for multiple requestors where only one causes the resource to be fetched and all are notified when it's available?

Tags: design-patterns

What would be a suitable design pattern where multiple threads could request from a resource, but only one of them succeeds.  All the other requesters are notified when the resource is available.

For example, two or more threads requests a resource file which is obtained over the network.  The first one in blocks the other two threads.  The first thread generates a single request and then waits for the resource to become available just like the other two waiting threads.

When I say waiting, they don't really wait blocking, they check a variable or something because this is already part of a thread-pool so those other threads can do other work.

What is that design pattern called?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `Mutex.TryLock()`?

*Disclaimer: In Windows/.NET terminology; names and syntax may differ in other platforms and languages.*

Comment: Kindof... and this is roughly how I've implemented it.  Just wondering if my design is the best.. it might be ok.

Comment: In my opinion: If it works, keep it simple and don't speculate about the overused buzzword “pattern”.

Comment: I'm not out to use a pattern for the sake of it.  But choosing the most appropriate pattern can make the design significantly simpler and less error prone.  I'm not exactly using TryLock.  I'm using locks, but not the way described here.

Answer (score 0):

You have roughly three choices:

- Use the idea of 'futures' - in java, there's an interface java.util.concurrent.Future, but the idea is easily expressed in other languages - with the first thread creating a future and putting it in a global map, and later threads picking it up and either waiting for it to be realized or checking it when they can and acting on it when it's ready.
- Use futures, but have the first thread hand off to another thread (from a pool) to do the actual loading; this involves more threads, but makes the code for the main threads simpler, because they don't have to worry about whether they're the first thread or not.
- Put the use of the loaded resource in a callback, registered by the main threads, and called by the thread which loads the resource.

I quite like the second option, but the choice really depends on your particular requirements.